# File IO with Gradle

Tags: file-io, gradle

I have a file called `changelog.md` that has text that looks like this:

```
# Changelog
## Version (version id)
(stuff in here)
***
## Version (older version id)
(other stuff in here)
***
```

I want to capture the text in between the first occurrences of `## Version` and `***` and store it in a string. How would I go about doing this? I know that Gradle supports Groovy runtime, and found some tutorials of how to do something like this online, but how would I intertwine all of that to get the most minimalistic approach? Is Groovy even required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regex expert. but this snippet should give you `(stuff in here)`

```
def versions = file("changelog.md").text =~ /(## Version)(.*)\n(.*)/
def latestVersionFromChangeLog = versions[0][3]
```

Comment: Well, I want the `(stuff in here)`, not the project version. I already have that handled in my program, so reading it from a changelog isn't necessary.

Comment: I fixed my answer so you get the right content  `(stuff in here)`

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, that `latestVersionFromChangelog` is the content that I want? Remember that `(stuff in here)` consists of multiple lines of text.